# (python) best way to implement multiple input from the user

Tags: python, input

im asking my user for information and i tend to have alot of input fields and i find it really repetitive to keep using inputs line after line.

current code:

```
a= input(str("a value:  "))
b= input(str("b value:  "))
c= input(str("multiple c values:  ")).split(" ")
```

(values changed from my projects, same use though)

all of my input fields are working as intended but i would like to clean up the code.

Comment: Write a function that takes a list of prompts and names, and returns a dictionary that maps the names to the responses.

Comment: There's no need to wrap a `str` literal in a call to `str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if you have a special case (`c` here) you have to treat it separately anyway. Ignoring special cases you can use a dict along these lines:

```
val = {}
keys = ['a', 'b']

for key in keys:
    val[key] = input(key+(" value:  "))
```

Then use `val['a']` instead `a` in your code.

If you don't want to use a dict and have to use `val[...]` everywhere, you can use this line instead

```
globals()[key] = input(key+(" value:  "))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to store the input where the keys are variables and values are questions. Then in the loop replace the values/questions with inputs

sample code:

```
dictr = {"a": "a value: ", "b": "b value: ", "c": "multiple c values: "}

for key, value in dictr.items():
    dictr[key] = input(value).split(" ")

print(dictr)
```

output:

```
a value: a
b value: b
multiple c values: a b c
{'a': ['a'], 'b': ['b'], 'c': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

Comment: I like this :) just to slow to type mine :D

Comment: what if the desired value for `a` is `'a a a'`?

Comment: That is the problem while im typing the code above, he just needs to manipulate the list and use .join()

Answer (score 0):

Split up your code in questions and the questioning, like this:

```
# question and whether it's a multi one
questions={"a": False,
           "b": False,
           "c": True}

answers={}
for k, v in questions.items():
    q="multiple {} values: " if v else "{} value: "
    answers[k]=input(q.format(k))

print(answers)
```